# add submenu in customer dashboard left navigation

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-account

I want to extend the customer account dashboard menu with a new section shown in the picture below.
What is the best practice to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can simple add these link by adding your phtml file

```
<customer_account>
        <reference name="left">
            <block type="core/template" name="test_dashboard-left" after="-" template="test/test-left.phtml"
                />
        </reference>
    </customer_account>
```

your phtml file

```
<div class="block block-account">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span>My Custom Section</span></strong>
    </div>

    <div class="block-content">
        <ul>
<li>My Ownl lInk</li>
<li>My Ownl lInk1</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Qaisar in which file must I add the customer_account section and what else do I need to configure? i.e. a new module or only a template?

Comment: in local.xml of your theme or customer.xml it upto you

Comment: i update my answer kindly check it..

Comment: Qaisar can you please show the path where to place the new files?

Comment: maindirecotry/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/test/test-left.phtml

Comment: Thx thats it :)

Comment: If you require thus much spooning, you should not really be doing this at all. Please make an effort to study the application and start with http://store.pulsestorm.net/products/no-frills-magento-layout

Answer (score 2):

Follow this

Make sure You should edit theme file not a core file

Step 1: Activating The Module

```
\app\etc\modules\Istockphp_Customerpage.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--step 1: registering the module-->
<config>
    <modules>
        <Istockphp_Customerpage>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Istockphp_Customerpage>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Step 2: Config File

```
\app\code\local\Istockphp\Customerpage\etc\config.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Istockphp_Customerpage>
          <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Istockphp_Customerpage>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <blocks> <!--Block folder-->
            <istockphp>
                <class>Istockphp_Customerpage_Block</class>
            </istockphp>
        </blocks>
    </global>

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <istockphp>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Istockphp_Customerpage</module>
                    <frontName>custompage</frontName>
                </args>
            </istockphp>

            <customer>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <!--name / before: change existing -->
                        <istockphp before="Mage_Customer">Istockphp_Customerpage</istockphp>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </customer>
        </routers>

        <layout>
          <updates>
            <istockphp>
                          <!--app\design\frontend\default\default\layout\customer\custompage.xml-->
              <file>customer/custompage.xml</file>
            </istockphp>
          </updates>
        </layout>

    </frontend>
 </config>
```

Step 3: Controller File

```
\app\code\local\Istockphp\Customerpage\controllers\AccountpageController.php

<?php class Istockphp_Customerpage_AccountpageController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {     protected function _getSession() {         return Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');     }     public function preDispatch() {         parent::preDispatch();             if (!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->authenticate($this)) {
                $this->setFlag('', 'no-dispatch', true);
        }
    }

    // http://localhost/istockphp_magento/custompage/accountpage/index
    public function indexAction() { // landing page
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();

    }

}
```

Step 4: Block

```
\app\code\local\Istockphp\Customerpage\Block\Customer.php

<?php

class Istockphp_Customerpage_Block_Customer extends Mage_Customer_Block_Account_Dashboard  {

}
```

Step 5: Adding link in Customer Dashboard

```
\app\design\frontend\default\default\layout\local.xml

<layout version="0.1.0">
    <!--add link to the customer panel-->
    <customer_account>
        <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer">
                <name>custom page</name>
                <!--Customer Block/AccountpageController.php-->
                <path>customer/accountpage/</path>
                <label>Custom Page</label>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </customer_account>

</layout>
```

Step 6: Update Layout

```
\app\design\frontend\default\default\layout\customer\custompage.xml

<layout version="0.1.0">
     <!--Istockphp\Customerpage\controllers\AccountpageController.php-->
    <customer_accountpage_index translate="label">
        <label>Custom Page</label>
            <reference name="head">
                    <action method="setTitle"><title>Custom Page</title></action> <!--Page Title-->
            </reference>
        <!-- Mage_Customer -->
        <update handle="customer_account"/>
        <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
            <!--name in config file / Istockphp\Customerpage\Block\Customer.php-->
            <block type="istockphp/customer" name="istockphp" before="-" template="customer/custom_customer_page.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </customer_accountpage_index>
</layout>
```

Step 7: Template File

```
\app\design\frontend\default\default\template\customer\custom_customer_page.phtml

<div class="page-title">


<h1><?php echo $this->__('Customer Custom Page') ?></h1>


</div>


<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>

 Welcome to my custom page


<div class="buttons-set">


<a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('customer/account/') ?>"><small>&laquo; </small><?php echo $this->__('Back') ?></a>

</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

Comment: I found this tutorial too. But I want to add a complete new tab/section 'My custom section' with new links (see the pic)

Comment: Use same just add H1 tag before and then create another phtml and then call your .xml file