# Magento add submenu in customer dashboard left navigation

Tags: magento-1.9, navigation

I have added my custom menu in left navigation of customer dashboard page but i also want to add sub-menu to my custom menu.

Is there any way to add sub-menu ?

I have created menu using below code

```
<customer_account> 
  <reference name="customer_account_navigation"> 
    <action method="removeLinkByName"><name>billing_agreements</name></action>           
    <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="test">
      <name>info_edit</name>
      <path>test/index/getinfo/</path>
      <label>Custom menu</label>
    </action>                   
 </reference> 
</customer_account>
```

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/88602/extend-customer-account/88630#88630 follow these..

Comment: Not working for me.